# Retrieve origin of AUFS layer

Tags: docker

In Docker, AUFS layers are stored into `/var/lib/docker/aufs`. In this directory are two subsir `diff` and `mnt` containing AUFS layers. For debugging purpose I'd like to:

1. Retrieve which image/container the layer "belongs" to
2. Retrieve which command caused this layer to be created

I could not find any useful information in Docker documentation.

Many thanks

Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72